# React Native 0.55.2 Android looks for index.android.js

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am currently using React Native 0.55.2 for my project and I am trying to integrate the React Native Navigation from wix into my native projects (both ios and android). I followed their instructions in the website and successfully set it up for ios (it was able to build and run successfully in the emulator). I was also successful in building it for android (see image, I used npm run android), however, when I run it on the android emulator, the image below pops up. I don't know why it tries to look for android.index.js even if my react native project is setup for the latest one which only needs 1 index file which is index.js

Build Success (npm run android):
[image]

Android Emulator Error:
[image]

Comment: Yes, Now there is common file in the new version it's Called index.js. Now index.android.js  and index.ios.js removed in the new version.

Comment: That's the weird thing, I don't have the index.android.js and index.ios.js. only index.js

Comment: You are build the android build using command.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my answer can resolve your problem but normally if I hit this error, I will follow below step:

1. Clear cache
2. Close the terminal and uninstall my app, simulator
3. Delete folder node_module  and run yarn again (optional)
4. Run react-native run-android
5. my version: 55.4

Comment: One morething , your project name should not contain hyphens

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java files of the android project, like Main Application.java or MainActivity.java. They contain a method that returns the bundle file name and you'll see it contains 'index.android' instead of 'index'.

You should be able to find this place easily also by using 'git grep'.